# Not able to find angular JS element using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, protractor

```
<div data-ng-transclude="" data-ng-style="{fontSize:fontSize}" layout="column" layout-align="center center" flex="25" data-fittext="" data-fittext-max="16" style="margin: 5px 10px 5px 1px; font-size: 5.7px;" class="ng-scope">
<span class="ng-scope">&nbsp;</span>
<span style="color: #ebeded; font-size: 12px;" class="ng-binding ng-scope">UPCHARGE</span>
</div>
```

I want to identify if span element with text "UPCHARGE" is present or not. How to identify the element with protractor.

Comment: Can you please update question with the ways you tried and failed with? Also, have you tried using element locators? for ex - `element(by.xpath('//span[contains(text(),"UPCHARGE")]'))`?

Comment: Give it an ID value and then do by.id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use byCssContainingText + isPresent()

```
var elm = element(by.cssContainingText('span', 'UPCHARGE'));
expect(elm.isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText
http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent